# ¿Cómo puedo crear aplicación con create-react-app 5.0.0? - No hay más soporte para la instalación global de Create React App

Tags: reactjs, npm

Cuando fui a crear un proyecto nuevo con el comando `npx create-react-app nombre-app`, me salió lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice tal cual aparece en el log y desinstalé globalmente create-react-app pero me sigue saliendo esa advertencia cuando intento crear un proyecto. Según la [documentación de create-react-app para actualizarlo](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/), se actualiza el paquete cada vez que se crea un nuevo proyecto, pero esto no sucedió.

**Versión de npm:** 8.6.1
**Versión de node:** v16.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando en los [issues del repositorio de create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11754) encontré una solución alternativa con el comando:

- `npx create-react-app@5.0.0 app-name`
- o `npx create-react-app@latest app-name --use-npm`

Para arreglar el comando `npx create-react-app` hay que borrar manualmente la caché de npx con: `npx clear-npx-cache` y ya se podrá usar el comando por defecto.

Más sobre esto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-appyou-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-whi).